# How to feed data from google form to google bigquery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-forms

I want to feed data from google form to google bigquery, how can I do with google script? I want a example code.

Thank,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is:

1. Save Google Form responses in spreadsheet. [How-to link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en).
2. Setup a BigQuery external table following [Query A Google Sheets Spreadsheet From BigQuery](https://chrispenner.ca/posts/bigquery-sheets).
3. (Optional) Use [CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_new_table_from_an_existing_table) to copy data to BigQuery. (Can also be BigQuery scheduled query).

Note that, with 1) and 2) being done. You don't need single line of 'code' to feed your form response to BigQuery. It is just queryable.